# Do we really not have an "off-topic" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just went to VTC [this question about Apple and Google terms of service](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/82124/can-i-create-a-unique-bid-auction-app-for-android-and-ios), and discovered that we do not appear to have a "this question is not about the law" close reason.  The apparently-available close reasons:

- Duplicate
- Community-specific: specific legal advice
- Community-specific: belongs on another site
- Needs details or clarity
- Needs more focus
- Opinion-based

Am I missing something, or do we really not have a "This question is not about the law or legal processes" close reason?  And if not, should we?

Answer (score 1):

The "Community Specific: Other" reason can be used in such cases, at the minor cost of typing out a statement that the question is not on-topic, and perhaps a few details on why.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we really not have an "off-topic" close reason?

Some of the close reasons available imply that the post being VTC is off-topic.

A person who thinks that the underlying post is not about law could select "*Community-specific: belongs on another site*" or "*Needs details or clarity*", insofar as the post is unclear on how the law or legal principles are relevant.

Regarding the post you mention, some users who VTC also stated that the post is "not about the law". Their conclusion is wrong, though.

The OP's inquiry was about Google's/Apple's terms of service. That pertains to *legal terms and language*, which is listed on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Someone knowledgeable of Google's/Apple's app world might also be able to determine whether the OP's topic pertains to contract law or constitutes a quasi-contract, both matters being on topic. Users' adverse reaction --again, from their misunderstanding of the post-- appears to have prompted the author to delete his post.

If anything, the OP should have provided the section(s) of the ToS which are confusing to him. Absent that information, users should have suggested the OP to delve in the ToS and, accordingly, edit his post to make it more specific to where he is having difficulty.